# Change text size of listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout, android-listview

I am trying to change the listview text size (it seems to be pretty large by default) and am running into an error.  I think the idea is to assign a textview to the listview and change the properties of that textview, but I am beginning to think I am going about this the wrong way.  It would be greatly appreciated if somebody wouldn't mind glancing over what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the error:

```
12-03 21:59:26.894  24751-24751/my.obd2connector E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.obd2connector, PID: 24751
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.obd2connector/my.obd2connector.MyCar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at my.obd2connector.MyCar.fillList(MyCar.java:120)
            at my.obd2connector.MyCar.onStart(MyCar.java:92)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code to populate the listview where I am trying to change the size and color:

```
public void fillList() {   
        carList.add(make + " " + model + "\n" + vin);

        mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyCar.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, carList);

        mylistView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter);
        TextView tv = (TextView)mylistView.getAdapter();
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        mylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: which adapter you are using ?

Comment: Its: public ArrayAdapter<String> mylistAdapter;  I need this to fill the ListView of strings.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)mylistView.getAdapter();
```

is causing the problem. You cannot cast an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Instead you need to create a custom layout for your ListView and in there change the properties of the TextView that you use on the layout.

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) covers details of creating a simple custom layout.

Comment: I sure wish I saw this tutorial when I first started lol, thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the default layout of the ListView to custom layout

Instead of using like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_listview_item, list);
```

you can use customLayout.xml:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customLayout, list);
```

customLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listTextView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

or you can use like this:

```
  listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations()) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    textView.setTextSize(12);

    return textView;
}
```

});

Comment: I have tried this... whenever I make my custom layout, it does not show up when I type android.R.layout.     It only seems to show simple_listview_item and the others.  Is there a certain folder it goes in to recognize it?

Comment: you can use second example

Comment: I would call that after I i do setAdapter(), in the filllist method?

Comment: you can set adapter in listview like that

Answer (score 1):

If you want chnage list item's view size. You can do it in your xml file of listitem, and pass it to your adapter.

**Note :** TextView id should assign android.R.id.text1

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.

```
 mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout, list );
```

Can also try

```
mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this, android.R.layout.simple_listview_item, android.R.id.listTextView , list);
```